# Problema en base de datos mysql al pasar datos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
    <?php
include 'conexion_formulario.php';

  $incidencia1 = $_POST['incidencia1'];
  $incidencia2 = $_POST['incidencia2'];



if(isset($_POST['incidencia1']) || empty($_POST['incidencia1']) && 
   isset($_POST['incidencia2']) || empty($_POST['incidencia2']) )
//*  isset($_POST['incidencia3']) || empty($_POST['incidencia3']) && 
//*  isset($_POST['incidencia4']) || empty($_POST['incidencia4']) && 
//   isset($_POST['incidencia5']) || empty($_POST['incidencia5']) && 
//   isset($_POST['incidencia6']) || empty($_POST['incidencia6']) && 
//   isset($_POST['incidencia7']) || empty($_POST['incidencia7']) && 
//   isset($_POST['incidencia8']) || empty($_POST['incidencia8']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia9']) || empty($_POST['incidencia9']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia10']) || empty($_POST['incidencia10']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia11']) || empty($_POST['incidencia11']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia12']) || empty($_POST['incidencia12']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia13']) || empty($_POST['incidencia13']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia14']) || empty($_POST['incidencia14']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia15']) || empty($_POST['incidencia15']) && 

    //consulta para insertar
    $insertar = "INSERT INTO respuestas_tbl (incidencia) VALUES ('$_POST[incidencia1]','$_POST[incidencia2]')";
    //Ejecutar consulta
    $resultado = mysqli_query ($conexion, $insertar);



    if (!$resultado){
        echo 'ERROR ! Datos no enviados';
    }else{
        echo 'Datos enviados';
    }
//Cerrar conexion
    mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Comment: Por favor di algo más que código: qué estás intentando hacer, qué error estás teniendo, cuál es el contexto, etc.

Comment: Esta consulta `INSERT INTO respuestas_tbl (incidencia) VALUES ('$_POST[incidencia1]','$_POST[incidencia2]')` nunca va a funcionar, ya que estás indicando una sola columna `incidencia`  y dos valores. Si quieres insertar **dos filas** casa una con una incidencia, lo más fácil y seguro sería usar una consulta preparada y pasarle cada valor dentro de un bucle por ejemplo. Si por el contrario, se trata de dos valores dentro de una misma fila, debes indicar cómo se llama esa segunda columna.

Answer (score 0):

Estas enviando dos parametros en tu consulta SQL $_POST[incidencia1] y $_POST[incidencia2] pero solo especificaste un campo que deba recibirlo [incidencia]

Comment: saludos @Ezeur te inivito a ver como responder, el usuario no da especificaciones dle error espera que el aclare y das tu respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

El numero de campos en el listado del `insert` no coincide con el values y el if solo afecta una linea ya que no hay  `{}` no es claro te sugiero los siguientes cambios:

```
if((isset($_POST['incidencia1']) || empty($_POST['incidencia1'])) && 
   (isset($_POST['incidencia2']) || empty($_POST['incidencia2'])) ) {
...
}
```

y

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO respuestas_tbl (incidencia,incidencia2) VALUES ('$_POST[incidencia1]','$_POST[incidencia2]')";
```

quedaria asi:

```
<?php
include 'conexion_formulario.php';

  $incidencia1 = $_POST['incidencia1'];
  $incidencia2 = $_POST['incidencia2'];

    $insertar = "INSERT INTO respuestas_tbl (incidencia,incidencia2) VALUES ('$_POST[incidencia1]','$_POST[incidencia2]')";

if((isset($_POST['incidencia1']) || empty($_POST['incidencia1'])) && 
   (isset($_POST['incidencia2']) || empty($_POST['incidencia2'])) )
//*  isset($_POST['incidencia3']) || empty($_POST['incidencia3']) && 
//*  isset($_POST['incidencia4']) || empty($_POST['incidencia4']) && 
//   isset($_POST['incidencia5']) || empty($_POST['incidencia5']) && 
//   isset($_POST['incidencia6']) || empty($_POST['incidencia6']) && 
//   isset($_POST['incidencia7']) || empty($_POST['incidencia7']) && 
//   isset($_POST['incidencia8']) || empty($_POST['incidencia8']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia9']) || empty($_POST['incidencia9']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia10']) || empty($_POST['incidencia10']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia11']) || empty($_POST['incidencia11']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia12']) || empty($_POST['incidencia12']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia13']) || empty($_POST['incidencia13']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia14']) || empty($_POST['incidencia14']) &&
//   isset($_POST['incidencia15']) || empty($_POST['incidencia15']) && 

{
    //consulta para insertar
    $insertar = "INSERT INTO respuestas_tbl (incidencia,incidencia2) VALUES ('$_POST[incidencia1]','$_POST[incidencia2]')";
    //Ejecutar consulta
    $resultado = mysqli_query ($conexion, $insertar);



    if (!$resultado){
        echo 'ERROR ! Datos no enviados';
    }else{
        echo 'Datos enviados';
    }
//Cerrar conexion
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
?>
```